# ファイル数が多い場合にRaspberryPi4のSambaの転送が異常に遅い

Tags: raspberry-pi, samba

ラズパイ4にSambaをインストールしてラズパイに接続されたNTFSファイルシステムのHDDを共有フォルダとして設定しました。クライアントPC(Ubuntu and Mac)とはルーター経由の無線で繋げています。

問題は、クライアントPCからファイルマネージャーを通じて共有フォルダを見ようとすると動きが遅く、ファイル名/フォルダ名が表示されるまでラグが生じていることです。
ですが、通信速度が遅いというわけではなく、大きなファイルをコピー＆ペーストする場合に遅いということはありません。
HDDへのアクセス速度はラズパイ上では問題ないため、ファイルシステムの問題ではなさそうです。
また、scpを用いた多数のファイルを含むフォルダの転送では十分に満足できる速度が出ています。（もちろん事前にZipで固めておいた方が速いのですが）
sambaを使った転送だとscpの場合と比べ、同じフォルダを転送するのに10倍近い時間がかかっています。

以上のことから、通信環境やファイルシステムの問題ではなく、Sambaの設定の問題だと考えていますがSambaの設定で多数のファイルを含むフォルダの転送が異常に遅くなる場合、どのような原因が考えられるのでしょうか。

以下、OSとSambaのバージョン情報です。
OS: rasbian10
Samba: 4.9.5

Comment: SambaじゃなくてSMBが重たいからじゃないの？https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/storage/file-server/troubleshoot/slow-file-transfer

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。そのようです。多数の軽量なファイルを扱うのは他のプロトコルの方が良さそうでした。

Answer (score 0):

調べて見つけた情報にはなりますが、Samba マウントに使用するファイルシステムを NTFS から ext3 や ext4 にすることで転送速度が改善した、という事例があるようです。

[Slow samba transfer speed on RPi4 to a usb 3.0 drive (10,4mb/s)](https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?p=1494071&sid=4a714556812c44e30de0878ea1ef5b9d#p1494071)

> I formatted my drives as NTFS and got 30MBps transfer speeds.
> Put the drives back to ext3 and I"m getting 90MBps (for large files).
> So I guess the survey says, avoid using NTFS if you want fast transfers and use ext3 instead.

Comment: ご指摘ありがとうございます。
試しに適当なUSBをext4にフォーマットして早くなるか試してみたのですが、改善できませんでした。